# Why du command is showing 501MiB?

Tags: linux, binary, dd, du, block-device

I'm making a 500MiB binary file like this:

```
$: dd if=/dev/zero of=mlinux.img bs=1048576 count=500
```

Then when I do:

```
$: du -b mlinux.img
```

It returns exactly 524288000

But when I do:

```
$: du -BMiB mlinux.img
```

It returns 501MiB

Why not exactly 500MiB ?

Comment: Disk usage != file size. See `--apparent-size` of `du`.

Comment: If I try bs=1M count=500, I get exactly 500MiB

Comment: 500MiB with `du`? I have `501` anyway. Both files are 524288000 bytes in size and use 1024008 blocks (check with `stat`)

Comment: I tried on another machine : dd if=/dev/zero of=mlinux.img bs=$((2**20)) count=500. Then du -BMiB (coreutils V 8.32) returns exactly 500MiB. So I'm a bit confused...

Comment: By default `du` returns number of blocks allocated in filesystem, not file size. The same file may require different number of blocks in different circumstances. Check your file with `stat -c "size: %s, blocks: %b, block size: %B" mlinux.img`. Multiply number of blocks by block size and divide it by 1048576 with rounding up. This is how `du -BMiB` works.